# UITableview reloaddata with animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a `UITableView` which is populated from array and a drop down list.
If I select any row of drop down list the array will be inserted with new values and tableview should get reloaded.

How to animate the tableview with new array contents?

Animation like I want to show the row one by one. i tried this method

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray )indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation { 
NSIndexPath rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[names count] inSection:0];
 NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil]; 
[tableDetails reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 }
```

Comment: What kind of animation ? what you have try to do this?

Comment: animation like i want to show the row one by one . i tried this method    - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{
    
    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[names count] inSection:0];
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
    [tableDetails reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    
}

Comment: put this code in your question so someone can help u better.

Answer (score 131):

To add to the correct answer, if you want to reload **all** sections in your `UITableView` you will need to do the following:

**ObjC**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]);
NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

---

**Swift**

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections)  
let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: range)               
self.tableView.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
```

This will reload everything in the table view with an animation. Like a boss.

Comment: This assume the number of section does not changed. I secured it with this test `[self.tableView numberOfSections] == [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]` else I just call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: Yes that's a thorough way of handling it.

Comment: @AxelGuilmin you're so right, it crashes otherwise!

Comment: Swift 3 - let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections)
            let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: range)
            self.tableView.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .automatic)

Comment: @TimWindsorBrown how to reload table view with new data "Different data from the original array "

Comment: Using performBatchUpdates with closure passing reload call looks best use case here.

Answer (score 83):

**Swift 5:**

```
UIView.transition(with: tableView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.tableView.reloadData()}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIView.transition(with: myTableView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.myTableView.reloadData()}, completion: nil)
```

---

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(myTableView, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.myTableView.reloadData()}, completion: nil)
```

I went with this in Swift

Comment: this is the best solution because it allows to reload sections with different number of rows before and after the call

Comment: I visually prefer  tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)
It also handles different number of items before and after the call

Answer (score 54):

use this method,

```
[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: It works not correctly if you have more than one section or number of sections is changing during reload

Comment: @AlexeyF then you would insert them all into that NSIndexSet, and call the method above. If you can't do it, there's something wrong with your code design.

Comment: Also it doesn't give the right effect if you want to keep the section header but not rows..

Answer (score 28):

In Swift 3 you can simply add the following `extension` to `UITableView`:

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadData(with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation) {
        reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<numberOfSections), with: animation)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was an awesome solution to my problem. Thanks bud!

Comment: Great solution. For those using swift 4, UITableViewRowAnimation has been renamed UITableView.RowAnimation.

Answer (score 23):

You first tell the tableView to expect updates with `beginUpdates`. Then update the relevant sections (if your tableView has only one section then just pass zero for the section number). Here's where you specify the animation - you can play around with it to get the effect that you want. After that you call `endUpdates` on the tableView. The typedef for UITableViewRowAnimation specifies:

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
   UITableViewRowAnimationRight,
   UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
   UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
   UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
   UITableViewRowAnimationNone,
   UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,
   UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic = 100
} UITableViewRowAnimation;
```

Play around to see which one you want. Even selecting `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` can have a nice effect sometimes.  Table update code below:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` functions. Check [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Check this [reloadData with Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419472/have-a-reloaddata-for-a-uitableview-animate-when-changing) which already answered your question.

Comment: but where i have to put the code ? [tableDetails reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade] ?

Comment: after selecting your dropdown, you might call one method, put this code there.

Comment: drop down in the sense it is uitableview only i call the didselect row at indexpath and then i will populate the array with new contents and then i call the [tableview relaoaddata].

Comment: then do this in your `didselectrow`

Answer (score 4):

Below method is supported by tableView for animation :

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

Usage :

```
//Reload tableView with animation
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Different types of animation available are :

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewRowAnimation) {
UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
UITableViewRowAnimationRight,           // slide in from right (or out to right)
UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
UITableViewRowAnimationNone,            // available in iOS 3.0
UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,          // available in iOS 3.2.  attempts to keep cell centered in the space it will/did occupy
UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic = 100  // available in iOS 5.0.  chooses an appropriate animation style for you    };
```

Hope this might help!

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this and my `Table` is `Animated` with smooth animation

//Put this code where you want to reload your table view

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView transitionWithView:<"TableName"> 
                      duration:0.1f 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                    animations:^(void) {
                        [<"TableName"> reloadData];
                    } completion:NULL];        
});
```

Comment: Terrific idea, solves numerous problems (e.g., need to avoid crash on last row being deleted when using other methods, etc.).  A sneaky way to make a jump-reloadData into a smooth reloadData.  Plus 500!

Answer (score 3):

Try Animating while Transition Change of a view while reloading UITableView

```
[UIView transitionWithView:_yourTableView 
                  duration:0.40f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^(void) {[_yourTableView reloadData];}  
                completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5:**

```
let section = 0
tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: This will only work for section = 0 but will not work when different sections are there.

Answer (score 0):

in will dislplaycell paste this code it will animate add the new cell to tableview

```
let rotationTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 50, 0) 
cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform
cell.alpha = 0.0
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05 * indexPath.row) {
           cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
           cell.alpha = 1.0
       }
```