# How to animate the removal/addition of tableView cells when using multiple sections while the number of sections has the possibility of changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a `UITableView` with many sections, each section contains items with a certain letter of the alphabet(Alphabetically sorted). The user has the ability to add more data to this table, so when they add a new item that goes in a section that is not there, a new section must be created. Same problem when deleting, if the last item in a section is deleted the whole section would be removed. How would I animate this?

> I have found something similar to this: [UITableview reloaddata with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576921/uitableview-reloaddata-with-animation)

But that does not help me. It recommends using this method(In swift):

```
[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This works great if you have the same number of sections before and after the reload, but mine does not. The number of sections could change causing a crash.

Comment: you have to make sure, you dont have to change tableview while editing is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose you mentioned above, you should not reload data. For adding the new section you should use,

```
- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

For deleting the section you should use,

```
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```