# UIView Transition like Contacts.app

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm interested in transitioning a UIView similar to the way the Contacts app does it when you tap edit on a contact. [You can see a [crummy] GIF](http://cl.ly/image/1i183T3Y1q14) of it here for reference. The values that have already been defined slide down into their positions to be edited, and new fields fade in.

I've looked through the UIView transition documentation, but didn't see how to do exactly this. A `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` isn't quite it. I suppose I could animate each field into it's place then fade into the full view, but that seems like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: It's probably a UITableViewAnimation... possibly specific to the Group TableView style.

Comment: I think you're right. Looking at the docs for `UITableView` now. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setEditing:animated:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacts.app definitely looks like a `UITableViewAnimation`, as RazorSharp says in the comment above. The effect would have to be done manually if you aren't using `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I basically wanted the same transition like the contacts app. I have registered 2 cells, one for viewing that uses `UILabels` and one for editing that contains a `UITextField`. I think switch cell identifier in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` depending on if I'm editing or not. To get the fade animation I use

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [UIView transitionWithView: self.tableView
                  duration: 0.35f
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations: ^(void)
     {
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
                completion: nil];
}
```

This was taken from the below question

[Have a reloadData for a UITableView animate when changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419472/have-a-reloaddata-for-a-uitableview-animate-when-changing)

This gives a subtle fade. Another option I found was to call
`[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Similar affect but I thought it was a little less clean