# Can I remove items from my UITableView data source and have my UITableView animate the row removal without specifying exact index paths?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, datasource

Is such a thing possible?

Basically the data source for my `UITableView` is a binary tree. I'm going to remove the children of one of the nodes in the tree, and I want the table view to automatically animate the update, which will remove the rows corresponding to these children.

I know I can use `beginUpdates()`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths()` and `endUpdates()` but finding all those rows is a computational annoyance (it's far from negligible). Is there any way for the `UITableView` to just reload with an animation?

Comment: No. `UITableView` has not enough information to do the animation after reloaded. That's why you need to call those methods in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13261683/1077601 suggests you can put your `[self.tableView reloadData];` inside a UIView animation block.