# Realm Notification is not triggered when NSPredicate changes

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have a simple ticked off list in Realm, where I am using `NotificationToken` to check for updates in the datasource and hereafter updates the tableView with the following items:

```
class Item : Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var isTickedOff = false
    dynamic var timeStamp : Date?
}
```

The model:

```
var items: Results<Item> {
    get {
        let results = self.realm.objects(Item.self)
        let alphabetic = SortDescriptor(property: "name", ascending: true)
        let tickedOff = SortDescriptor(property: "isTickedOff", ascending: true)
        let timestamp = SortDescriptor(property: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
        return results.sorted(by: [tickedOff, timestamp, alphabetic]).filter("isTickedOff = %@ || isTickedOff = %@", false, self.includeAll)
    }
}
```

I have a switch in my tableview, where the user can change the `self.includeAll` property.

When inserting, deleting items or selecting them (resulting in setting them to `isTickedOff` or !`isTickedOff`) triggers the notification and updates the tableView. However, changing the `self.includeAll` property does not trigger the notification even though the `items` property is modified. I could include `self.tableView.reloadData()` when the user triggers the switch, but I would like the more smooth animations through the notification.

Is it me, who understands notifications wrong or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm doesn't observe external properties, so it can't know when a property that is being used in a predicate query has changed, and to then subsequently generate a change notification off that.

When you access `items` the next time, that will give it a sufficient event to recalculate the contents, but by that point, it won't trigger a notification.

Obviously, like you said, the easiest solution would be to simply call `tableView.reloadData()` since that will force a refetch on `items` but there'll be no animation. Or conversely, [like this SO question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419472/have-a-reloaddata-for-a-uitableview-animate-when-changing), you can call `tableView.reloadSections` to actually enable a 're-shuffling' animation.

Finally, it might be a rather dirty hack, but if you still want it to trigger a Realm-based change notification, you could potentially just open a Realm write notification, change the `includeAll` property, and then close the write transaction to try and 'trick' Realm into performing an update.

One final point of note. I might not have enough information on this, so this might be incorrect, but if you're registering a Realm notification block off the `items` property, be aware that the way you've implemented that getter means that a new object is generated each time you call it. It might be more appropriate to mark that property as `lazy` so it's saved after the first call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @TiM. 'tableView.reloadSections' does the trick and looks much smoother than 'tableView.reloadData'. Changing the 'includeAll' property inside a write transaction does not seem to do the trick. I would actually have expected the 'items.addNotificationBlock' to listen to changes to the 'items' property even though nothing changes in the underlying realm.

Comment: No worries @Krabbas! Glad I could help! Ahh okay. That's good to know at least. The change notification block responds to when the underlying Realm data changes in such a way that will change the contents of the `Results` object. It gets a bit more hairy when compounding that with an `NSPredicate` relying on external properties.