# Correct way to delete item uitableview swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a UitableView with 3 section (3 cell), In section 1 I have a list of item where user can delete using button, all delete process is good but when I delete a item; the uitableview goes to top and goes to bottom (is something like reload the view) and I want that

When user delete a item only remove from position this is my code

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var value: Int = 0
        if(section == 0){
            value = 1
        }else if(section == 1){
            value = items.count //20
        }else if(section == 2){
            value = 1
        }
        return value
    }

    @objc func delete_item(sender: UIButton){
        let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tv_items)
        guard let indexPath = tv_items.indexPathForRow(at: point) else{
            return
        }
        tv_items.beginUpdates()
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tv_items.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tv_items.endUpdates()
    }


    cell.btn_delete.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn_delete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delete_item), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156274/deleting-a-row-from-a-uitableview-in-swift-3

Comment: I can delete, my problem is te scroll i delete an item an app srolltoTOP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419472/have-a-reloaddata-for-a-uitableview-animate-when-changing

Comment: Are you using `estimatedHeightForRowAt`? If so, try disabling this.

Comment: estimatedHeightForRowAt no in my code I do'nt have that, how can i disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `estimatedHeightForRowAt`, disable this and use `heightForRowAt` function.

Alternatively, use this after `endUpdates()`:

```
tv_items.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

If you have a constant row height, you can use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80 // or any constant height
}
```

If you need varying height based on content, lemme know what the content is so I can help.

Comment: how can I use heightforRowat, I am new

Comment: @Israel, I've updated my answer to show setting a constant height. If you need varying height based on content, lemme know. Happy coding!

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept this answer. If not, lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method and I think it will solve your issue:-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
return 50.0 // height of the row (Eg. 50.0)
}
```